# Google Sheets filename in cell via formula instead of a script?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

Is there a `FORMULA` that will display the name of the file in a cell?

I've found scripts that will do it, formulas that will display the sheet name, but no luck finding a formula that will show the filename.

If I have to resort to the script, so be it.  But I'd like to use formula if possible.

If this has been asked before, please point me to the post and I will delete this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a native function in Google Sheets that I can use to get the Spreadsheet name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76111654/is-there-a-native-function-in-google-sheets-that-i-can-use-to-get-the-spreadshee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No—unfortunately this is not possible with any built-in function.**

The only way to do this with a function  would be to use AppScript to write a custom one, which is essentially back to writing a script.

Comment: @TC76 Mind accepting this answer so we can remove this as the most-viewed “unanswered” question in the [google-sheets-formula] tag? Sadly almost 4 years later the answer to your question is still “no” :(

Answer (score 0):

But adding this App Script will return the correct value (but slowly):

```
function GetGoogleSheetName() {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```