# Is there a native function in Google Sheets that I can use to get the Spreadsheet name?

Tags: google-sheets

I know that I can get the spreadsheet name using a Google App Script custom function, but that does not work for me, because I need this function to work when I make a copy of the spreadsheet and once you make a copy, you have to authenticate the function and the person who will use that copy will not do that.

I need a native function that returns the name of the Spreadsheet. Apparently Excel has a function that does that `=cell('filename',a1)`, but I could not find a similar function in Google Sheets. I suspect it does not exist, but you guys are way more clever than I am, so it is worth a shoot...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No—unfortunately this is not possible with any built-in function.

Comment: You can see the full list of funtions [here](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273), also If you have a Workspace account you could also try submitting this idea [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en)